# Replicate HIVE database to Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hive, sqoop

Situation:
I'm reading files from hdfs with Spark and creating around 1000 Hive tables in 30 minutes.

Requirement:
As fast as possible I need to have these 1000 tables on Oracle as well.

My thoughts:
1. Load same dataframe to Hive and then to Oracle via jdbc within the same Spark application.
2. Load data to Hive. Sqoop tables from Hive to Oracle.

Any other ideas? Basically I need to replicate whole Hive database with ~1000 tables to Oracle.

Extremely appreciate any advice.

Comment: May be add some sizing details?

Comment: @thebluephantom tables are small up to 5k records.

Comment: tables of 5k in Hive, sounds odd...

Comment: @thebluephantom I know that's not the perfect scenario, but it is what must be done and I'm looking for the best way to achieve this.

Comment: but overwrite, incremental? u need to be clearer

Comment: @thebluephantom all tables should be incremental. Sorry, if details are not clear. I'm looking for generic solution that would not depend on sizes or table types.